# marking read articles

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have an app that displays external links to a site, they are all articles. These articles are in the database. I'm currently looking into a solution that would show the user new articles on their next visit, via a simple tag like "NEW" etc.

I have made a table with cols ID, user_id, article_id, read.
I have started work on the models and controller but basically I need to pass the article ID and user ID to a jQuery function when a user clicks that article so that the data can be inserted into the data showing that the article has been read. Thus the "NEW" label would not be shown for that article anymore.

Is this the best way to do this? I need some help on how to approach the jQuery side of things.

Thank you.

Comment: I have done it using the JOIN with parameter left. This returns empty values too. Therefore I could check against a null value and show the NEW tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what sawny said, you won't need another controller. Just define a function in your controller to handle this

baseurl.com/controller/function/linkID

In the function you'll want to make sure that you store the Artilce ID and User ID in a seperate table.

Table Name: article_views
Fields: userID, articleID

That way you can join on this table to help you display which articles are infact new for each user.

Once that's been store you can redirect the user to the actual article.

Comment: Thanks, that is the current problem I am facing. I dont know how to display or check if the articles are "NEW" or read, because the join would not show anything if the table is empty. Therefore I dont know how to do a check against each article.

Comment: Pass the read articles as an array to the view. Then when printing them out use the PHP function in_array($article, $articles_array) in an if statement. If its not in that array, display it as "new".. if it is display it as "read".

Answer (score 1):

If you use javascript it won't work for people without javascript. I had used an out link like `?out=*articleId*`. Then you can save down that userX has clicked on linkX. Then you redirect the user width `header("Location: *realURlFromDB*");`.

Comment: Ah wow I didnt think of that, this way I can actually log many other things like clicks. Thank you. For this to work I would need another controller to handle this and then redirect?

Comment: @viperfx I'm new to MVC myself, so I am not sure. But I had done a function `out` in my controller `logger`. That way I get all logging functions in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the JOIN with parameter left. This returns empty values too. Therefore I could check against a null value and show the NEW tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//query that fetch unread articles
$query = "
    SELECT 
        articles.* 
    FROM 
        articles
    LEFT JOIN
        read_articles
            ON articles.id != read_articles.article_id
    WHERE
        read_articles.user_id = 1
";

/**

Test db data
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Article 1'),
(2, 'Article 2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `read_articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `read_articles` (`id`, `article_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1);
```